# On click scroll div horizontally in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, scroll, angular6, scrollto

I am using Angular 6 and bootstrap framework for css. I want to scroll the div horizontally on click on left/right buttons.

I want to scroll the below div, chapter names may contain one chapter or more than 1 i.e 1-10 chapters. How to achieve the horizontal scroll on click of let and right arrow buttons.

```
<div style="margin-top:52px;" *ngFor="let chapter of chapters; let i = index" >
<li style="display: inline-block;float: left; padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;"> chapter.name </li>
</div>
```

For reference, in the below example we have movie names with image. i am using only text,

[image]

my current ui is looking like below and i need to achieve that on click event scrolling functionality,

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question but your HTML is wrong, you can't have a `<div>` around an `<li>` Tag. Also: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: @cloned, actually i am new to angular and i have to show the list of chapter names in one row. if chapters are more, then it should move to horizontal scroll to right on click on next button and horizontal left scroll on click on left arrow button. No idea how can i achieve this in angular 6. i updated question with image

Comment: @cloned, i have edited my question with images to explain the problem am facing. pleas check

Comment: @user3599302, you got my last reply in the comments against the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a carousel... which has arrows for the scrolling effect that you're aiming for:

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='containerDiv'>
    <carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide" [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset" [showIndicators]="false" [noWrap]="!noWrap"
     [interval]="false" [startFromIndex]="0" (slideRangeChange)="onSlideRangeChange($event)">
        <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
            <img [src]="slide.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <p>some optional text {{index}}</p>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-carousel-multilist',
  templateUrl: './multilist.html',
  styles: [`
  ::ng-deep a.carousel-control-prev, a.carousel-control-prev:hover {left:-7% !important;}
  ::ng-deep .carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-next:hover {right:-8% !important;}
  slide{margin:5px;}
  .carousel-caption{position:relative; text-align: center; padding: 15px 0 0 0; bottom: 0;}
  `]
})
export class DemoCarouselMultilistComponent {
  itemsPerSlide = 4;
  singleSlideOffset = false;
  noWrap = false;

  slidesChangeMessage = '';

  slides = [
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/2.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/3.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/4.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/5.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/6.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/7.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/8.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/2.jpg'}
  ];

  onSlideRangeChange(indexes: number[]): void {
    this.slidesChangeMessage = `Slides have been switched: ${indexes}`;
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwos8)

Comment: Thanks, yeah carousel but i don't want work with images. i want to to scroll only with chapter names like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcJkU.png

Comment: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1081/0328/files/Screen_Shot_2019-07-09_at_11.15.40_AM.png?17 this i want to achieve

Comment: Thanks Akber, but when i integrate with my code i mean my dynamic code. it's throwing error: CarouselComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at CarouselComponent.moveMultilist (ngx-bootstrap-carousel.js?f1ee:937)
    at CarouselComponent.move (ngx-bootstrap-carousel.js?f1ee:433)

Comment: after clicking on right navigation arrow, that error is throwing. i have written code to add the values in loop : for (let v in this.chapters)
            {
                console.log(this.chapters[v].comicdetaileddata_episode);
                this.slides.push({
                    name: this.chapters[v].episode
                    })
            }

Comment: Ok i will try. If i use the same code of stackblitz and integrate it's working like a charm. but, when i add the slides =[ ] dynamically and click on navigation, i'm getting that error

Comment: When you load slides dynamically and then do slides.length, what do you get?... You might want to safety operator '?' in the arc also... Check:  `<img [src]="slide?.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">`

Comment: i am not using image to show.. only caption i am showing.in place of image in slides i am adding chapter names. length am getting correctly. I tested with intitial with one slide available and then in ngOnInit() i am dynamically adding the slides dynamically. then first time it is showing chapter names. when i click on next and then come to previous, it's showing only one initial slide name. but length is 6 it's showing

Comment: If length is 6... And you're getting 4 slides on the first go, clicking next will give you 4 more slides (but you only have 2 more, which is why the error)... Can you try adding 2 more data just for testing? If you set [single slide offset] to true, you can go around this issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding [single slide offset] to true worked. But, the names are coming randomly on each load. i want in serial as it is pushed and i want the text in one single line. because and spacing between each name also. i tried changing css of slide. not reflecting. i want like this: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1081/0328/files/Screen_Shot_2019-07-09_at_11.15.40_AM.png?17

Comment: Print the array on console and verify the sequence of your array; for single line, I can only help if you recreate the issue by changing the attached stackblitz

Comment: oh in array itself it's coming in random way from for each loop. I have updated stackbliz with big names to get in single line.

Comment: You'd have to fork my stackblitz, then make the changes; save those changes; share the stackblitz URL with me here... Enjoying your persistence and will to get this going... This is probably an answer I have spent the most comments on without making a single point ;-)

Comment: Am really sorry. Please cehck this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwos8-c7h6x3?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts

Comment: add this to your TS file... `::ng-deep .carousel-caption p {font-size:1.5vw}`

Comment: Yeah, it's working. But according to my design, i have to use font-size: 16px for the text(i.e chapter names); can we make increasing the width of the div or any alternative ?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwos8-7wggnj?file=app/ngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts

Comment: if the font-size is fixed to 16px, you'd have to change divs from 4 in a row to two or one in a row

Comment: But, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1081/0328/files/Screen_Shot_2019-07-09_at_11.15.40_AM.png?17 here i have to show 4 at-least in first display

Comment: what if this first display is on a mobile? with `font-size:16px` if the names are longer in length, you wouldn't get the 4 boxes - you can check and share the URL also.

Comment: In mobile only 2 per slide and in desktop 4 per slide https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwos8-7wggnj?file=app/ngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts